# Laravel: Many to Many relations

Tags: php, laravel

I have a setup like this.

**document model**

```
public function plates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Plate')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**plate model**

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and pivot table like this

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('document_plate', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->integer('plate_id')->unsigned()->index();
          $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned()->index();

          $table->primary(['plate_id', 'document_id']);

          $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Now I understand this relations as many to many which means I can assign many `plate` id's to many `document` id's right?

Here is what I have been  playing with.

```
$plates = [
    'plate_id_1' => 1,
    'plate_id_2' => 2,
    'plate_id_3' => 3,

  ];


  $docs = [
    'recipe_id' => 1,
    'procedure_id' => 2,
  ];

  // attach many docs to plates
 $plate       =   Plate::findMany($plates);
 $doc         =   Document::findMany($docs);

 $plate->documents()->attach($doc->id);
```

What I want is: I want, when the `user` selects `documents` from drop down, to assign those selected documents to the **many** selected plates. So it's many docs with many plates. I have tried and checked the docs http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

both `sync` and `attach` methods.

The code above generates an error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::documents()

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Am I doing this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to retrieve a relationship for a model from an entire collection of models which won't work. I'm assuming your find many method is returning a collection of models based on the array of id's you pass into it.

If you want to attach many plates to a document, use:

```
$document->plates()->attach($plate_ids);
```

If you want to attach many documents to a plate:

```
$plates->documents()->attach($document_ids);
```

---

Edit:

There's probably a more elegant way of doing this without changing your code too much but you could do something like the following:

```
$plate_filter = [
    'plate_id_1' => 1,
    'plate_id_2' => 2,
    'plate_id_3' => 3,
];


$doc_filter = [
    'recipe_id' => 1,
    'procedure_id' => 2,
];

// attach many docs to plates
$plates =   Plate::findMany($plate_filter);
$docs   =   Document::findMany($doc_filter);

// Loop over the selected plates, attach selected docs
foreach( $plates as $plate ) {

    // $doc_ids = get your document id's here, use lists or something
    $plate->documents()->attach($doc_ids);
}

// Loop over the selected docs, attach selected plates
foreach( $documents as $document ) {

    // You already have your plate id's in your first array,
    // simply use array_values to return a new array containing
    // only the plate id's
    $document->plates()->attach(array_values($plate_filter));
}
```

It'd be handy if you could pass a collection into attach(), I'm not sure if you can and I cant find any references to people doing it on google.

Comment: I don't understand this. Could you please edit my code above and show it to me. I need first to find the id's  I assume.. right?

Comment: I have tested your updated code. It works, only on the second `foreeach` you get an `Integrity constraint violation - 1062 Duplicate entry '1-1'`

Comment: @user3641381 if you read the comments i made in the code i said in the first loop you would have to get the id's of the documents you wanted to attach.